# .NET application posts to GearHost and works fine, but does not work on AWS

Tags: mysql, asp.net, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2017

I have a web application that I would like to migrate from GearHost to Amazon Web Services (Elastic Beanstalk). The web application uses a mysql server that is hosted by GoDaddy. When I try to publish the project to AWS using Visual Studio, the publishing process goes smoothly and there are no errors, however I get a connection timeout when I try to access the site. If i replace `https` with `http` I get "HTTPS Required" which leads me to believe the issue is not with the server itself, but with my application.

Does AWS require you to use their database server? 
Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I tried an older version of IIS in the AWS settings, the webpage loaded once and now it does not work on refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use an AWS database, but you do need to open up the GoDaddy firewall to allow traffic to go back and forth between your new AWS website and the GoDaddy database.

Comment: Could you provide a reference?

Comment: I just googled "GoDaddy firewall database" and got this: https://www.godaddy.com/help/connect-remotely-to-databases-4978